# Add PDF download option to FancyBox in WordPress

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm using Fancyapps' FancyBox on a WordPress site and it's great. The only thing is the client wants to add the ability to download or view a PDF.

Thus, when you click an image on the site, you get the FancyBox modal window displaying large version of that image. In the bottom right corner of the FancyBox modal window I've added a button that says 'PDF'.

I need to be able to attach a PDF to each post in WordPress and have the relevant PDF download/display (depending on your browser and plug-in) when the 'PDF' button is clicked.

I found where to add the PDF button in the fancybox source directory (jquery.fancybox.pack.js)  but I have no idea what the global variable would be to link to the PDF attached to each post.

Here is the code (line 34):

```
if(c=a.current.title)c=d('<div class="fancybox-title fancybox-title-'+b.type+'-wrap">'+c+"</div><a class='pdf_dl' href='{href}' target='blank'>PDF</a>").appendTo("body"),"float"===b.type&&(c.width(c.width()),c.wrapInner('<span class="child"></span>'),a.current.margin[2]+=Math.abs(parseInt(c.css("margin-bottom"),10))),c.appendTo("over"===b.type?a.inner:"outside"===b.type?a.wrap:a.skin)}};d.fn.fancybox=function(b){var c=d(this),e=this.selector||"",f,g=function(g){var h=this,j=f,k;!g.ctrlKey&&!g.altKey&&!g.shiftKey&&!g.metaKey&&!d(h).is(".fancybox-wrap")&&
```

Any ideas? I may be going about this in the wrong way.. Thank you!

Comment: Is there only one PDF per post? And only one image? If there are multiple images: how do you tell below which image the PDF link should be shown?

Comment: Ideally if there are multiple images, the PDF would apply to all of them so would be same PDF for all images in that post.

Answer (score 0):

There are two relevant topics here

#### The client side: Fancybox

As you have said, you need to change the Fancybox window and add the download link. I think is is a bad idea to manipulate the original source file of Fancybox (you even seem to have posted a part of the [minified](http://www.crockford.com/javascript/jsmin.html) production version which is hardly readable). What are you going to do if a new version of Fancybox is released? You would have to manually port your changes to the new version.

Instead, make use of the [Callbacks that Fancybox provides](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs). For example, hook your own javascript into the `beforeShow` callback and manipulate the Fancybox window elements there. You need to pick up the URL (see below) and create the desired link to it.

#### The server side: Wordpress

In order to know *which* PDF file you should link to, Wordpress needs to put the URL into the page. You probably want it to be hidden, because you only show it when the Fancybox is opened. A simple way would be using a hidden link:

```
<a href="/wp-content/uploads/myfile.pdf" id="pdflink" style="display: none;"></a>
```

The implementation depends on your needs. In your Wordpress theme, you can use [`wp_get_attachment_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_url) and [`get_posts()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link#Display_attached_images_and_titles_as_a_list) to get the information out of the database.

Here's a suggestion how to modify the Wordpress example code to a function that returns the URL of the first PDF attachment of any post (untested, though):

```
function getPdfUrlForPost( $postId ){
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'post_status' => null,
        'post_parent' => $postID
    );

    $attachments = get_posts( $args );
    if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
          $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID );   
          if( substr(strrchr($url,'.'), 1) == 'pdf' ){
              return $url
          }
        }
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you pixelstik for the direction and code. I will try to implement this and get back to this thread.